# Country flag emoji not getting using country code in

Tags: android, locale, country-codes

I want to get country flag using country code which should be supported to all versions from `API 19 to API 28`. For that i searched lot and found answer and i picked the code which was marked as accepted answer.

I am using code from that answer

```
 private String localeToEmoji(Locale locale) {
    String countryCode = locale.getCountry();
    Log.v("Asdasdasdasd", countryCode+" ; "+locale.getDisplayCountry());
    int firstLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCode.toUpperCase(), 0) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
    int secondLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCode.toUpperCase(), 1) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
    return new String(Character.toChars(firstLetter)) + new String(Character.toChars(secondLetter));
}
```

I am using this function by,

```
 Locale current = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(getResources().getConfiguration()).get(0);
 txt.setText(localeToEmoji(current));
```

But this is not working in `Kitkat` and `Lollipop`. It just showing country code not country flag. I have tested in both devices now.

So what is the best way to retrieve country flag using country code.

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private String localeToEmoji(Locale locale) {
    String countryCode = locale.getCountry();
    int firstLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCode, 0) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
    int secondLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCode, 1) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6;
    return new String(Character.toChars(firstLetter)) + new String(Character.toChars(secondLetter));

}
```

here `0x41` represents uppercase A letter and `0x1F1E6` is `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A` in the Unicode table and use are using `toUpper` again, this may cause problem

Answer (score 0):

@Piyush updated answer:
(note that my code requires capitalised country code)

`build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
```

`countryToEmojiCode`:

```
object CountryHelper {
    private const val flagsAsciiOffset = 127397
    fun countryToEmojiCode(countryCode: String) = StringBuilder().apply {
        val simCountryIso = if (countryCode == "UK") {
            "GB"
        } else {
            countryCode
        }
        simCountryIso.forEach {
            appendCodePoint(it.toInt() + flagsAsciiOffset)
        }
    }.toString()
}
```

Usage:

```
val emojiInitializer = EmojiCompat.init(BundledEmojiCompatConfig(requireContext()))

emojiInitializer.registerInitCallback(
        EmojiCompatHelper { initialised: Boolean ->
            if (initialised) {
                val flagEmoji = EmojiCompat.get().process(flagEmojiCode).toString()
            }
        })
```

Initialiser callback for the emoji library:

```
class EmojiCompatHelper(private val initialised: (Boolean) -> Unit): EmojiCompat.InitCallback() {
    override fun onInitialized() {
        super.onInitialized()
        initialised(true)
    }

    override fun onFailed(throwable: Throwable?) {
        super.onFailed(throwable)
        initialised(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) to Flag emoji using Kotlin functions.

```
fun countryFlag(code: String) = code
  .uppercase()
  .split("")
  .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
  .map { it.codePointAt(0) + 0x1F1A5 }
  .joinToString("") { String(Character.toChars(it)) }

println(countryFlag("in"))
// output
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension:

```
fun String.toFlagEmoji(): String {
        // 1. It first checks if the string consists of only 2 characters: ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 two-letter country codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol).
        if (this.length != 2) {
            return this
        }
    
        val countryCodeCaps =
            this.uppercase() // upper case is important because we are calculating offset
        val firstLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCodeCaps, 0) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6
        val secondLetter = Character.codePointAt(countryCodeCaps, 1) - 0x41 + 0x1F1E6
    
        // 2. It then checks if both characters are alphabet
        if (!countryCodeCaps[0].isLetter() || !countryCodeCaps[1].isLetter()) {
            return this
        }
    
        return String(Character.toChars(firstLetter)) + String(Character.toChars(secondLetter))
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
holder.countryFlag.text = countryCode.iso2.toFlagEmoji()
```